# Implement while loop in Reactor to fetch latest Elasticsearch index

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spring-webflux, project-reactor, reactive

My index name in reactive elastic search are as follow:

```
logs-2020.08.18
logs-2020.08.17
logs-2020.08.16
```

It will be created daily basis.

I wanna fetch the latest index name and get the logs using reactiveElasticsearchClient or spring data.
Is it possible?

I tried the following way in my spring webflux application:

I have the below code snippet to find index availability:

```
public Flux<Log> getLogFromLatestIndex(String serialId) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    String currentIndex = StringUtils.EMPTY;
    boolean indexExists = false;
    while (!indexExists) {
        currentIndex = String.format("logs-%s”, format(cal.getTime(), "yyyy.MM.dd"));
        indexExists = isIndexExists(currentIndex).block();
        cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -1); // Decrease day 1 until you find index
    }

    SearchQuery searchQuery = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
            .withQuery(matchQuery("serialId", serialId))
            .withIndices(currentIndex)
            .build();

    return reactiveElasticsearchTemplate.find(searchQuery, Log.class);
}

public Mono<Boolean> isIndexExists(String indexName) {
    return reactiveElasticsearchClient.indices().existsIndex(new GetIndexRequest().indices(indexName));
}
```

How do I fetch boolean value without using block here

```
indexExists = isIndexExists(currentIndex).block();
```

Obviously I will get the below error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: block()/blockFirst()/blockLast() are blocking, which is not supported in thread reactor-http-nio-2
```

Comment: Is your app a Spring WebFlux app? Do you want to return a `Mono<String>` in the end which is the name of the latest index?

Comment: Yes it is spring webflux app. I need latest index name to search some data. Like below: 
SearchQuery searchQuery = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
                .withQuery(matchQuery("serialId", serialId))
                .withIndices(currentIndex)
                .build();

        return reactiveElasticsearchTemplate.find(searchQuery, Log.class); // Finally I will return flux.

Comment: @MartinTarjány I have updated my question

Comment: where is the `cal` variable coming from?

Comment: Sry, updated now

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Flux.generate` and `(take/skip)(Until/While)` to do a while loop in reactor.

Notes:

- replaced `Calendar` with `LocalDate` as that is immutable and fits better with functional/reactive programming.
- the `isIndexExists` method returns a `Tuple` to have the reference for the index name but obviously it can be replaced with some more descriptive class as needed

```java
public Flux<Log> getLog(String serialId) {
    return Flux.generate(LocalDate::now, this::generateNextDate)
               .map(day -> String.format("logs-%s", day.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy.MM.dd"))))
               .concatMap(this::isIndexExists)
               .skipUntil(Tuple2::getT2) // check index exists boolean and drop non-existing ones
               .next() // takes first existing
               .flatMapMany(tuple -> findLogs(tuple.getT1(), serialId));
}

private LocalDate generateNextDate(LocalDate currentDay, SynchronousSink<LocalDate> sink) {
    sink.next(currentDay);
    return currentDay.minusDays(1);
}

private Mono<Tuple2<String, Boolean>> isIndexExists(String indexName) {
    return reactiveElasticsearchClient.indices().existsIndex(new GetIndexRequest().indices(indexName))
            .map(exists -> Tuples.of(indexName, exists));
}

private Flux<Log> findLogs(String index, String serialId) {
    // your other ES query here
}
```

Comment: Thanks buddy. I think it will not take the currentDay first, it will always fetch currentDay-1 as first check right?

Comment: Oops, yes, you're right. Updated the answer so now it starts with current day.

Comment: It is working fine as standalone code. But the same code is not working in application as it keep on calling onNext method. I am getting "more than one call to onnext" error. Pls assist.

Comment: I can just guess with so little info. Are the index names generated as expected? Are any of them present in the ES cluster? Where the error is coming from? Is it from the code in the answer or some other part which raise this exception? Can you create an example which produce this error?

Comment: index names are fine. Yes it is present in ES cluster. The error is coming from the code we written, not from anywhere. Since onNext is keep on calling, am getting "Connection prematurely closed BEFORE response". I am having exactly the same code which we have here.

Comment: Unless you can provide an example which reproduces the error, I'm not able to help.

Comment: I dont know where to add my code. Please check my code in answer section.

Comment: It's better to add plus info to the original question. I didn't spin up a Spring Boot app and ES, I was hoping for some smaller example. I have an idea, though, so I updated my answer: use concatMap operator instead of flatMap. This will prevent calling ES for many indexes eagerly. If the issue still persists, then please share error message with stacktrace.

Comment: No error now with concatMap but I was looking out for logs-2020.08.19, but still it keeps printing all indices. 

logs-2020.08.23
logs-2020.08.22
logs-2020.08.21
logs-2020.08.20
logs-2020.08.19
logs-2020.08.18
logs-2020.08.17
logs-2020.08.16
And so on. Once it reaches logs-2020.08.19, why it is searching other indices, that means multiple calls happening.

Comment: Although I got output, unwanted calls are happening which is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

application.yml

```
spring.data.elasticsearch.client.reactive.endpoints: ip1:9200,ip2:9200,ip3:9200
spring.data.elasticsearch.rest.uris: ip1:9200,ip2:9200,ip3:9200
```

Configuration.java

```
@Configuration
public class ElasticSearchConfig extends AbstractReactiveElasticsearchConfiguration {

    @Value("${spring.data.elasticsearch.client.reactive.endpoints}")
    private String elasticSearchEndpoint;

    @Override
    public ReactiveElasticsearchClient reactiveElasticsearchClient() {
        final ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration = ClientConfiguration.builder()
            .connectedTo(elasticSearchEndpoint.split(","))
            .withWebClientConfigurer(webClient -> {
                ExchangeStrategies exchangeStrategies = ExchangeStrategies.builder()
                        .codecs(configurer -> configurer.defaultCodecs()
                                .maxInMemorySize(-1))
                        .build();
                return webClient.mutate().exchangeStrategies(exchangeStrategies).build();
            })
            .build();
    return ReactiveRestClients.create(clientConfiguration);

    }
}
```

Controller.java

```
@GetMapping("/getLog/{serialId}")
public Flux<Log> getLog(@PathVariable String serialId) {
    return loggerService.getLog(serialId);
}
```

Rest are all your code. I am just printing index name inside map. Although I am having index logs-2020.08.21 in elastic search, it is keep on printing indices like logs-2020.08.20, logs-2020.08.19, logs-2020.08.18 and so on, eventually throws error.

Note: When I tried with single ip in application.yml, I got the same error.

```
public Flux<Log> getLog(String serialId) {
    return Flux.generate(LocalDate::now, this::generateNextDate)
           .map(day -> {
                System.out.println(String.format("logs-%s", day.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy.MM.dd"))));
                return String.format("logs-%s", day.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy.MM.dd")));
            })               
           .flatMap(this::isIndexExists)
           .skipUntil(Tuple2::getT2) // check index exists boolean and drop non-existing ones
           .next() // takes first existing
           .flatMapMany(tuple -> findLogs(tuple.getT1(), serialId));
}

private LocalDate generateNextDate(LocalDate currentDay, SynchronousSink<LocalDate> sink) {
    sink.next(currentDay);
    return currentDay.minusDays(1);
}

private Mono<Tuple2<String, Boolean>> isIndexExists(String indexName) {
    return reactiveElasticsearchClient.indices().existsIndex(new GetIndexRequest().indices(indexName))
        .map(exists -> Tuples.of(indexName, exists));
}

private Flux<Log> findLogs(String index, String serialId) {
    // your other ES query here
}
```